Android Studio Flutter the emulator process has terminated
I am trying to run emulator on android studio for flutter project. I has created a virtual device pixel 4 with R catagory android 11.0. I am keep getting the error "the emulator process has terminated". I had change the avd loction from c to because there was enough space on c. here are the logs of the run
At first it did showed a black phone screen for few sec but than
enter image description here
Update:
After going deeper i foung out that Vanguard anti cheat software is terminating the emulator. I did disable it from service but issue remains same. i don't want to uninstall it because of game. tell me if you have any solutions.
2024-08-06 21:48:23,081 [ 408177]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=test1, containerState=COMPONENT_CREATED, componentStore=E:\Flutter Projects\test1)ChangeListManager took 16 ms, ClangdSettings took 15 ms, DependencyValidationManager took 16 ms, DynamicElementsStorage took 125 ms, ExternalProjectsManager took 47 ms, GradleSettings took 31 ms, JsonSchemaMappingsProjectConfiguration took 31 ms, Kotlin2JvmCompilerArguments took 16 ms, ProjectLevelVcsManager took 16 ms, ServiceViewManager took 15 ms, ToolWindowManager took 16 ms, Vcs.Log.Tabs.Properties took 15 ms, XDebuggerManager took 147 ms, deploymentTargetSelector took 31 ms
2024-08-06 21:48:23,477 [ 408573]   INFO - #c.i.o.c.i.s.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 1763 ms
2024-08-06 21:52:55,993 [ 681089]   INFO - #c.i.o.v.n.p.FSRecords - Checking VFS started
2024-08-06 21:52:58,444 [ 683540]   INFO - #c.i.o.v.n.p.FSRecords - Checking VFS finished (healthy): VFSHealthCheckReport[healthy: true](FileRecordsReport[recordsChecked=57943, recordsDeleted=46009, childrenChecked=11889]{nullNameIds=0, unresolvableNameIds=0, notNullContentIds=46, unresolvableContentIds=0, unresolvableAttributesIds=0, nullParents=0, inconsistentParentChildRelationships=0, generalErrors=0), RootsReport(rootsCount=44, rootsWithParents=0, rootsDeletedButNotRemoved=0, generalErrors=0), NamesEnumeratorReport(namesChecked=32382, namesResolvedToNull=0, idsResolvedToNull=0, inconsistentNames=0, generalErrors=0), ContentEnumeratorReport(contentRecordsChecked=142188, generalErrors=0)){timeTaken=2.425736800s}
2024-08-06 22:07:30,012 [1555108]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - "D:\Softwares\Android Studio All Files\Android_Studio_SDK\emulator\emulator.exe" -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Flutter_Pixel_4_API_30_A11.0 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300
2024-08-06 22:07:30,318 [1555414]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - [7720:6240:20240806,220730.318:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\MMUZAM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.16.db\attachments\2bccbbdd-94df-4b3c-85bf-d29170e2a959: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
2024-08-06 22:07:30,334 [1555430]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\MMUZAM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.16.db, detection is enabled for process: 5088
2024-08-06 22:07:30,334 [1555430]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Android emulator version 34.2.16.0 (build_id 12038310) (CL:N/A)
2024-08-06 22:07:30,334 [1555430]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Found systemPath D:\Softwares\Android Studio All Files\Android_Studio_SDK\system-images\android-30\google_apis_playstore\x86\
2024-08-06 22:07:30,568 [1555664]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - [8332:1828:20240806,220730.568:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\MMUZAM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.16.db\attachments\2bccbbdd-94df-4b3c-85bf-d29170e2a959: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
2024-08-06 22:07:30,599 [1555695]   WARN - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): Vulkan
2024-08-06 22:07:30,599 [1555695]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - 
2024-08-06 22:07:30,787 [1555883]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Ignore IPv6 address: 98d9:f97d:9901:0:b0bf:f97d:9901:0 (2x)
2024-08-06 22:07:30,787 [1555883]   WARN - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Failed to process .ini file D:\Softwares\Android Studio All Files\avd\Flutter_Pixel_4_API_30_A11.0.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
2024-08-06 22:07:30,787 [1555883]   WARN - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Vanguard anti-cheat software is detected on your system. It is known to have compatibility issues with Android emulator. It is recommended to uninstall or deactivate Vanguard anti-cheat software while running Android emulator.
2024-08-06 22:07:30,787 [1555883]   WARN - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - FeatureControl is requesting a non existing feature.
2024-08-06 22:07:32,222 [1557318]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - added library vulkan-1.dll
2024-08-06 22:07:32,383 [1557479]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - initialize: Supports id properties, got a vulkan device UUID
2024-08-06 22:07:33,357 [1558453]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.SdkEntity to files
2024-08-06 22:07:33,357 [1558453]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities com.intellij.platform.workspace.jps.entities.LibraryEntity to files
2024-08-06 22:07:33,560 [1558656]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=test1, containerState=COMPONENT_CREATED, componentStore=E:\Flutter Projects\test1)ExternalProjectsManager took 16 ms, GroovyConsoleState took 31 ms, Kotlin2JvmCompilerArguments took 16 ms, RemoteRepositoriesConfiguration took 16 ms, TaskProjectConfiguration took 15 ms, ToolWindowManager took 16 ms
2024-08-06 22:07:33,622 [1558718]   INFO - #c.i.c.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appActionsLocalSummary took 16 ms, CodeVisionSettings took 15 ms, FeatureUsageStatistics took 16 ms, FileTypeManager took 141 ms, GithubAccounts took 15 ms, GradleJvmSupportMatrix took 16 ms, KeymapManager took 16 ms, ScratchFileService took 15 ms
2024-08-06 22:07:34,273 [1559369]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\MMUZAM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.16.db, detection is enabled for process: 7568
2024-08-06 22:07:34,273 [1559369]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
2024-08-06 22:07:34,274 [1559370]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - IPv4 server found: 192.168.10.1
2024-08-06 22:07:34,274 [1559370]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Ignore IPv6 address: b0bf:f97d:9901:0:b0bf:f97d:9901:0
2024-08-06 22:07:34,274 [1559370]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Ignore IPv6 address: b0bf:f97d:9901:0:b0bf:f97d:9901:0 (2x)
2024-08-06 22:07:34,274 [1559370]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Ignore IPv6 address: a0c5:f97d:9901:0:b0bf:f97d:9901:0
2024-08-06 22:07:34,274 [1559370]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Ignore IPv6 address: a0c5:f97d:9901:0:b0bf:f97d:9901:0 (2x)
2024-08-06 22:07:34,275 [1559371]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Ignore IPv6 address: b8cb:f97d:9901:0:b0bf:f97d:9901:0
2024-08-06 22:07:34,275 [1559371]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Ignore IPv6 address: b8cb:f97d:9901:0:b0bf:f97d:9901:0 (2x)
2024-08-06 22:07:34,275 [1559371]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Ignore IPv6 address: 98d9:f97d:9901:0:b0bf:f97d:9901:0
2024-08-06 22:07:34,276 [1559372]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Critical:
2024-08-06 22:07:34,276 [1559372]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Warning:
2024-08-06 22:07:34,277 [1559373]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Warning:  (6x)
2024-08-06 22:07:34,277 [1559373]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Crash reports will be automatically uploaded to: https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
2024-08-06 22:07:34,277 [1559373]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - library_mode host gpu mode host
2024-08-06 22:07:34,277 [1559373]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
2024-08-06 22:07:34,277 [1559373]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - android_startOpenglesRenderer: gpu infoGPU #1
2024-08-06 22:07:34,277 [1559373]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Make: 1002
2024-08-06 22:07:34,277 [1559373]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Model: AMD Radeon R5 Graphics
2024-08-06 22:07:34,277 [1559373]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Device ID: 9874
2024-08-06 22:07:34,277 [1559373]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - I0806 22:07:32.220322    1232 HealthMonitor.cpp:279] HealthMonitor disabled.
2024-08-06 22:07:34,277 [1559373]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - createGlobalVkEmulation:995 Selecting Vulkan device: AMD Radeon R5 Graphics
2024-08-06 22:07:34,278 [1559374]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - I0806 22:07:33.326964    1232 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1276] Initializing VkEmulation features:
2024-08-06 22:07:34,278 [1559374]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - I0806 22:07:33.327005    1232 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1277]     glInteropSupported: true
2024-08-06 22:07:34,278 [1559374]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - I0806 22:07:33.327013    1232 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1278]     useDeferredCommands: true
2024-08-06 22:07:34,278 [1559374]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - I0806 22:07:33.327041    1232 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1280]     createResourceWithRequirements: true
2024-08-06 22:07:34,278 [1559374]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - I0806 22:07:33.327051    1232 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1281]     useVulkanComposition: false
2024-08-06 22:07:34,278 [1559374]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - I0806 22:07:33.327057    1232 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1282]     useVulkanNativeSwapchain: false
2024-08-06 22:07:34,279 [1559375]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - I0806 22:07:33.327081    1232 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1283]     enable guestRenderDoc: false
2024-08-06 22:07:34,279 [1559375]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - I0806 22:07:33.327088    1232 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1284]     ASTC LDR emulation mode: 2
2024-08-06 22:07:34,279 [1559375]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - I0806 22:07:33.327094    1232 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1285]     enable ETC2 emulation: true
2024-08-06 22:07:34,280 [1559376]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - I0806 22:07:33.327107    1232 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1286]     enable Ycbcr emulation: false
2024-08-06 22:07:34,280 [1559376]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - I0806 22:07:33.327125    1232 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1287]     guestUsesAngle: false
2024-08-06 22:07:34,280 [1559376]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - I0806 22:07:33.327130    1232 VkCommonOperations.cpp:1288]     useDedicatedAllocations: false
2024-08-06 22:07:34,280 [1559376]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - I0806 22:07:33.328534    1232 FrameBuffer.cpp:506] Graphics Adapter Vendor Google (ATI Technologies Inc.)
2024-08-06 22:07:34,280 [1559376]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - I0806 22:07:33.328562    1232 FrameBuffer.cpp:507] Graphics Adapter Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (AMD Radeon R5 Graphics)
2024-08-06 22:07:34,281 [1559377]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - I0806 22:07:33.328569    1232 FrameBuffer.cpp:508] Graphics API Version OpenGL ES 3.0 (4.5.14831 Core Profile Context 21.09.03.09 27.20.20903.9001)
2024-08-06 22:07:34,281 [1559377]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - I0806 22:07:33.328576    1232 FrameBuffer.cpp:509] Graphics API Extensions GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth32 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_APPLE_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_texture_buffer
2024-08-06 22:07:34,282 [1559378]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - I0806 22:07:33.328586    1232 FrameBuffer.cpp:510] Graphics Device Extensions N/A
2024-08-06 22:07:34,282 [1559378]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - AEHD is operational
2024-08-06 22:07:34,304 [1559400]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.xsave [bit 26]
2024-08-06 22:07:34,304 [1559400]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.avx [bit 28]
2024-08-06 22:07:34,639 [1559735]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Monitoring duration of emulator setup.
2024-08-06 22:07:34,652 [1559748]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.adb.AdbService - Device [emulator-5554] is offline (device state is `OFFLINE`)
2024-08-06 22:07:34,663 [1559759]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Using security allow list from: D:\Softwares\Android Studio All Files\Android_Studio_SDK\emulator\lib\emulator_access.json
2024-08-06 22:07:34,669 [1559765]   WARN - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - *** Basic token auth should only be used by android-studio ***
2024-08-06 22:07:34,670 [1559766]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - 
2024-08-06 22:07:34,675 [1559771]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - The active JSON Web Key Sets can be found here: C:\Users\M Muzammil\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\7568\jwks\066aa372-e8ba-48f2-a340-340840a6585d\active.jwk
2024-08-06 22:07:34,675 [1559771]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - 
2024-08-06 22:07:34,676 [1559772]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Scanning C:\Users\M Muzammil\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\7568\jwks\066aa372-e8ba-48f2-a340-340840a6585d for jwk keys.
2024-08-06 22:07:34,686 [1559782]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local, auth: +token
2024-08-06 22:07:34,686 [1559782]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - 
2024-08-06 22:07:34,699 [1559795]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Advertising in: C:\Users\M Muzammil\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_7568.ini
2024-08-06 22:07:35,206 [1560302]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - I0806 22:07:35.172534    1692 FrameBuffer.cpp:2853] setDisplayConfigs w 1080 h 2280 dpiX 440 dpiY 440
2024-08-06 22:07:35,207 [1560303]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - I0806 22:07:35.172807    1692 FrameBuffer.cpp:2866] setDisplayActiveConfig 0
2024-08-06 22:07:35,768 [1560864]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Loading snapshot 'default_boot'...
2024-08-06 22:07:35,785 [1560881]   WARN - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Device 'cache' does not have the requested snapshot 'default_boot'
2024-08-06 22:07:35,785 [1560881]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - 
2024-08-06 22:07:35,786 [1560882]   WARN - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Failed to load snapshot 'default_boot'
2024-08-06 22:07:36,428 [1561524]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Camera notification event: cameraNotification { }
2024-08-06 22:07:36,429 [1561525]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Not yet booted
2024-08-06 22:07:36,429 [1561525]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.streaming.emulator.EmulatorView - Received notification: cameraNotification { }
2024-08-06 22:08:11,222 [1596318]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - [8332:1828:20240806,220811.222:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\MMUZAM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.16.db\attachments\eb48a571-99a7-46ff-8490-e0763e8d3a95: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
2024-08-06 22:08:11,224 [1596320]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - [8332:1828:20240806,220811.224:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\MMUZAM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.16.db\attachments\eb48a571-99a7-46ff-8490-e0763e8d3a95: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
2024-08-06 22:08:11,227 [1596323]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - [8332:1828:20240806,220811.226:ERROR directory_reader_win.cc:43] FindFirstFile: The system cannot find the path specified. (3)
2024-08-06 22:08:11,773 [1596869]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.streaming.emulator.EmulatorController - android.emulation.control.EmulatorController/streamScreenshot call failed - UNAVAILABLE: io exception
2024-08-06 22:08:11,773 [1596869]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.streaming.emulator.EmulatorController - android.emulation.control.EmulatorController/streamNotification call failed - UNAVAILABLE: io exception
2024-08-06 22:08:11,788 [1596884]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.streaming.emulator.EmulatorController - Disconnected from Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 (5554)
2024-08-06 22:08:12,038 [1597134]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.adb.AdbService - Device [emulator-5554] is offline (device state is `DISCONNECTED`)
2024-08-06 22:08:14,986 [1600082]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - [8332:1828:20240806,220814.986:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\MMUZAM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.16.db\attachments\eb48a571-99a7-46ff-8490-e0763e8d3a95: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
2024-08-06 22:08:15,033 [1600129]   INFO - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
2024-08-06 22:08:15,048 [1600144]   WARN - Emulator: Flutter Pixel 4 API 30 A11.0 - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741819 

I tried reinstalled the emulator, trying a differnet one,Deleting the file called multiinstance.lock but nothing works.
